# Best way to store outputs from multi-threaded function calls

Tags: multithreading, julia

I have a function `f()` which returns a DataFrame, the number of rows of which I don't know in advance. I'm calling `f()` in a multi-threaded context. I'm storing the results like this:

```
results = [DataFrame() for _ in 1:100]

Threads.@threads for hi in 1:100
    results[hi] = f(df)
end
```

When I run this code, the memory usage blows up, presumably because `results` is having to constantly resize itself when it gets the size of the DataFrame [EDIT: this isn't true]. What is the best way to pre-allocate the results array so that the memory doesn't blow up?

**** UPDATE with MWE ****

```
function func(df::DataFrame)
    X = df[:time]
    indices = findall(X .> 0)
end

# read in R data
rds = "blablab.rds"
objs = load(rds);

params = collect(0.5:0.005:0.7);

for i in 1:length(objs)
    cols = [string(name) for name in names(objs.data[i]) if occursin("blabla",string(name))]
    hypers = [(a,b) for a in cols, b in params]

    results = [DataFrame() for _ in 1:length(hypers)]

    # HERE IS WHERE THE MEMORY BLOWS UP
    Threads.@threads for hi in 1:length(hypers)
        name, val = hypers[hi]
        results[hi] = func(objs.data[i])
    end
end
```

`df` is 0.7GB. When I run this piece of code my memory usage goes up to ~30GB!!! It seems like just accessing a column of `df` inside `func()` is copying the whole thing?

Comment: `results` array does not have to constantly resize itself. In fact, I do not think it *ever* resizes during the loop. Do you put this loop inside a function? Could you share a MWE for `f()` so that we can see the issue causing high memory usage more clearly? By the way, all the `results` hold is a pointer to your `DataFrame`s.

Comment: F() is too long to post, but I’ve narrowed down the issue to where the results of f() are being saved. If I merely call f() but don’t save the results to the list, there’s no issue

Comment: I do not think the problem is about the code snippet in your question. If the results of `f()` is not being saved, it can safely be reclaimed by garbage collector, hence your memory usage does not grow. So it does not say much about where the problem is. Maybe, you do not really have any problem. Maybe your `DataFrame`s are really big. You can check the size of one of your `DataFrame`s using `Base.summarysize(df)`. Creating a new minimal `f()` might help identify the problem quickly.

Comment: You're correct. I've posted a MWE.

Comment: `func` in updated MWE returns an `Array` of indices, each of which is an `Int64` assuming your architecture is 64-bit. Each `Int64` takes 8 bytes on memory. You are storing these arrays after each iteration. The memory therefore has to grow. The amount of this growth will depend on the number of rows of each `DataFrame` where `time` is greater than 0. Accessing a `DataFrame` column does *not* allocate memory. Accessing `DataFrame` is not the issue here. You must change your code to shrink memory usage. Maybe remove `findall`, just store results as a `BitArray`, i.e. just use (X.>0)...

Comment: If you could tell what you really want to achieve, we might help better. It seems you must change the way you code for your solution. Maybe take a look at `Query.jl`, it might help reformulating what you want to achieve. Aside from the memory problem, you also have a type-instability issue. `results` is created as an `Array` of `DataFrame`s but `func` returns an `Array` of `Ints`.

Answer (score 2):

Please find below two version of the same code - single and multi-threaded generating a `DataFrame` from a set of `DataFrame`s returned by `f()` function and having random length.

```
using Random
using DataFrames
using BenchmarkTools

function f(rngs::Vector{Random.MersenneTwister}, offset)::DataFrame
    t = Threads.threadid()
    n = rand(rngs[t+offset], 1:20)
    DataFrame(a=1:n,b=21:(20+n),t=t+offset)
end

function test_threads(rngs::Vector{Random.MersenneTwister})
    res = DataFrame([Int,Int,Int],[:a,:b,:t],0)
    lock = Threads.SpinLock()
    Threads.@threads for i in 1:100
        df = f(rngs,0)
        Threads.lock(lock)
        append!(res,df)
        Threads.unlock(lock)
    end
    res
end

function test_normal(rngs::Vector{Random.MersenneTwister})    
    res = DataFrame([Int,Int,Int],[:a,:b,:t],0)    
    for i in 1:100
        append!(res,f(rngs, i%2))
    end
    res
end
```

Now let us do the testing:

```
julia> rngs = [Random.MersenneTwister(i) for i in 1:2];

julia> @btime test_normal($rngs);

  891.306 μs (5983 allocations: 476.67 KiB)

rngs = [Random.MersenneTwister(i) for i in 1:Threads.nthreads()];

@btime test_threads($rngs);

  674.559 μs (5549 allocations: 425.69 KiB)
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. I see now that the problem is not in the way I'm storing the results. The memory issue is happening somewhere inside the function being called by each thread. Is it making a copy of the dataframe argument every time?

Comment: in my code `f()` creates a new data frame every time. However, `append!` in Julia contrary to Gnu R just adds elements to a `DataFrame` rather than recreating the entire new `DataFrame`